# Show that ${1\over\pi}\iint_{\Bbb D}|\psi'_\alpha|^2\ dxdy =1$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

> If $\psi_\alpha(z) = (\alpha-z)/(1-\bar{\alpha}z)$ for $|\alpha|<1$, prove that
> $${1\over \pi}\iint_{\Bbb D}|\psi'_\alpha|^2\ dxdy = 1.$$
> [Hint: The integral can be evaluated without a calculation.]

Direct calculation shows that $\psi'_\alpha(z) = (|\alpha|^2-1)/(1-\bar{\alpha}z)^2$. Note that $|\psi_\alpha'(z)|^2 = \psi'_\alpha(z)\overline{\psi'_\alpha(z)}$. Maybe I can consider the mean value property of harmonic function (because there's a conjugate). But the product of harmonic function is generally not harmonic and I'm stuck at this point. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing $\frac{1}{\pi}\int\int_\mathbb{D}|\phi_\alpha '|^2 dxdy$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944560/computing-frac1-pi-int-int-mathbbd-phi-alpha-2-dxdy)

Comment: @RobertZ That post is about integrating $|\phi'_\alpha|$ not $|\phi'_\alpha|^2$.

Comment: You are right! Sorry. Maybe it could be useful also for your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the multivariate change of coordinates formula, with $\psi_\alpha$ as your change of coordinates.  Note that $\psi_\alpha$ is a holomorphic bijection of the disk to itself!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Currently, I'm trying to interpret the integral as an area of the image of $\psi_\alpha$ which is a unit disk. Because there is a power $|\ |^2$ in the integrand, I'm not sure the direct calculation is a good way.

Comment: @onepotatotwopotato For a holomorphic function, the determinant of the Jacobian (thought of as a $2x2$ real matrix) **is** the square of the modulus (thought of as a complex number).